# matlab draw a line using user input values

Tags: matlab, user-interface, plot, matlab-figure

I want to draw a line using the inputs for values x1,y1 and x2,y2 from the gui edit text box and plot them on the axes.

[function](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vmv95.png)

Comment: Do not post code as an image!!!!!

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to convert the *graphics handle* itself to a number rather than converting the *contents* of the `uicontrol` to a number. To get the value, you'll want to use the `'String'` property of the `uicontrol` instead.

```
x1 = str2double(get(handles.edit1, 'String'));
```

You will want to do the same for all user-supplied values.